# In Rails how can I tell in my AJAX JS file what button was clicked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my Rails application I have a view notify.html.erb with multiple forms that are created dynamically based on a few different models, such as Child.rb and Friend.rb.

**notify.html.erb**

```
<% @user.children.order("created_at").each do |child| %>
  <%= form_for(child, :method => :put, :remote => true)) do |f| %>
    <div class="notify-name"><%= child.name %></div>
    <%= f.email_field :email, :required => true, :placeholder => "Email Address", :class => "invite-email" %>
    <%= f.submit "Invite", :class => "btn btn-primary invite-user-btn" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% @user.friends.order("created_at").each do |friend| %>
  <%= form_for(friend, :method => :put, :remote => true)) do |f| %>
    <div class="notify-name"><%= friend.name %></div>
    <%= f.email_field :email, :required => true, :placeholder => "Email Address", :class => "invite-email" %>
    <%= f.submit "Invite", :class => "btn btn-primary invite-user-btn" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The forms are set to remote => true so that they are handled by AJAX. In each controller update action, I have:

**children_controller.rb**

```
def update
    child = Child.find(params[:id])
    email = params[:child][:email]
    if child.update(child_params)
      UserMailer.invite_new_user(current_user, child.name, email).deliver_later
      respond_to do |format|  
        format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: documents_path) }
        format.js
      end  
    end
end
```

In my update.js.erb file, I want to be able to select the specific button that was clicked. But as you can see in my view above, there is nothing unique about the buttons (they're created dynamically based on the number of children and friends a user has and they each have the same class). How can I get the button that was clicked so I can update the value of that button?

Comment: Why can't you add an `id` to each button and then select by that?

Comment: @hashrocket I could but the ids would be random and unpredictable (there will be a different number of forms for each user). How would I know what ID to reference in the js.erb file to select the appropriate button? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field with child id

```
<% @user.children.order("created_at").each do |child| %>
  <%= form_for(child, :method => :put, :remote => true)) do |f| %>
    <div class="notify-name"><%= child.name %></div>
    <%= f.email_field :email, :required => true, :placeholder => "Email Address", :class => "invite-email" %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :id, value: child.id %>

    <%= f.submit "Invite", :class => "btn btn-primary invite-user-btn" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will submit `id` of a child in params

in controller

```rb
def update
  child = Child.find(params[:child][:id])
  email = params[:child][:email]

  if child.update(child_params)
    UserMailer.invite_new_user(current_user, child.name, email).deliver_later

    respond_to do |format|  
      format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: documents_path) }
      format.js
    end  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a hidden filed, each hard coded with specific value. Then you can get that params in view

```
% @user.children.order("created_at").each do |child| %>
  <%= form_for(child, :method => :put, :remote => true)) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'invitable_type', 'child' %>
    <div class="notify-name"><%= child.name %></div>
    <%= f.email_field :email, :required => true, :placeholder => "Email Address", :class => "invite-email" %>
    <%= f.submit "Invite", :class => "btn btn-primary invite-user-btn" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% @user.friends.order("created_at").each do |friend| %>
  <%= form_for(friend, :method => :put, :remote => true)) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'invitable_type', 'friend' %>
    <div class="notify-name"><%= friend.name %></div>
    <%= f.email_field :email, :required => true, :placeholder => "Email Address", :class => "invite-email" %>
    <%= f.submit "Invite", :class => "btn btn-primary invite-user-btn" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

now in your `update.js.erb` you can access it like

```
<% if params[:invitable_type] == 'friend' %>
// you js code to enable button for friend
<% elsif params[:invitable_type] == 'child' %>
// you js code to enable button for child
<% end %>
```